# how to screenshot entire phone screen with status bar in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been trying for a while now to capture a screenshot of the entire phone screen( with android status bar icons)...but am only able to capture my current activity in my app. I will appreciate if someone can help me out with java code for screenshoting  the entire screen not just my current activity in my app using a button

Comment: As far as I know you can't do that, if you tried `getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()` this will capture your activity only, I suggest you to use `MediaProjection` API, here's an example by CW : https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/FINAL/MediaProjection/andshooter/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/andshooter/ScreenshotService.java

Answer (score 0):

pls read this code from the link. It helped me with a similar situation like yours. [Screeenshot in android programmatically](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-take-screenshot-programmatically-in-android/)